# How to get Gmail Attachment using JavaScript before send via GET request

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, email-attachments, gmail-api

Currently I am working on Chrome extension I want particular email (i.e message_id=1543c2a6347d984c) attachment data. I got email message_id also get attachment file name (i.e abc.zip) but how to get that attachment and send back to my server using Ajax.

```
function getAttachments(userId, message, callback) {
  var parts = message.payload.parts;
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    var part = parts[i];
    if (part.filename && part.filename.length > 0) {
      var attachId = part.body.attachmentId;
      var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.attachments.get({
        'id': attachId,
        'messageId': message.id,
        'userId': userId
      });
      request.execute(function(attachment) {
        callback(part.filename, part.mimeType, attachment);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Calling

```
var userId="xyz@gmail.com"
    var message_id="1543c2a6347d984d";

    getAttachments(userId,message_id,function callback(filename,minetype,attachment){

console.log('File Name is '+filename);
console.log('MimeType is '+minetype);   
});
```

**Error :**
main.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parts' of undefined (function getAttachments line 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your message_id is a string, then you call `getAttachments` method and pass it as second parameter, in `getAttachments`, you call `message.payload.parts`, which means you want to get a property `payload` from a string, of course it is `undefined`.

Take a loot at [Users.messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#examples) and [Users.messages.attachments.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get#examples), you would need to first get the message, then get attachments from it.

```
function getAttachments(userId, message, callback) {
  var parts = message.payload.parts;
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    var part = parts[i];
    if (part.filename && part.filename.length > 0) {
      var attachId = part.body.attachmentId;
      var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.attachments.get({
        'id': attachId,
        'messageId': message.id,
        'userId': userId
      });
      request.execute(function(attachment) {
        callback(part.filename, part.mimeType, attachment);
      });
    }
  }
}

function getMessage(userId, messageId, callback) {
  var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
    'userId': userId,
    'id': messageId
  });
  request.execute(function(message) {
      callback(userId, message);
  });
}

var userId="xyz@gmail.com"
var message_id="1543c2a6347d984d";

getMessage(userId, message_id, function(userId, message) {
    getAttachments(userId, message, function(filename,minetype,attachment) {
        console.log('File Name is '+filename);
        console.log('MimeType is '+minetype);   
    });
});
```

Comment: so what is solution for that ?? lat's see this [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get#examples)

Comment: @DivyeshKanzariya, see my answer.

Comment: how to ask for permission https://mail.google.com/
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly that mansion

Comment: @DivyeshKanzariya, sorry but what do you mean?

Comment: how to define that scopes.

Comment: when i trying to use gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.attachments, it is throwing  gmail.is undefined